# ö in Latex - strange symbols

Tags: compilation, package, latex

In the acknowledgements of my paper I have to thank a German professor and his last name contains an ö. Every time I compile the file I end up getting an A with a tilde and an ü instead of an ö (see picture).

Does anyone know how to circumvent this?

Thanks for the support.

[image]

Comment: You can add your code directly to your question.

Comment: The strange symbols you see are caused by a mismatch between the encoding of your file and the option passed to the `inputenc` package. Which encoding does your .tex file have?

Answer (score 6):

The characters `ä`,`ö`,`ü` are called ["Umlaute"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut_(linguistics)) in german.
Maybe that does help you in some way.

I found [this TeX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745).
According to it, the encoding of `ö` should be `{\"o}` in LaTeX.

Comment: Since several years, utf8 encoding is the default in latex, so you can directly type the umlauts, no need to escape them any longer which can cause problems for hyphenation ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\ddot{o}`
If you need an ä `\ddot{o}`

[image]

Comment: The OP wants to produce an ö not an ä.

Comment: @TiagoA. The ä is really the tiniest of problems with this post -- it does not even produce anything close to an umlaut